# C++ error C2059

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

### Solved

---

When I try to compile this program i keep getting these errors:

> (50) : error C2059: syntax error :
>   '<='
>
> (50) : error C2143: syntax error
>   : missing ';' before '{'
>
> (51) : error
>   C2059: syntax error : '>'
>
> (51) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before '{'
>
> (62) : error C2059: syntax
>   error : 'else'
>
> (62) : error C2143:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class income {
private:
    double incm;
    double subtract;
    double taxRate;
    double add;
    char status;
public:
    void setStatus ( char stats ) { status = stats; }
    void setIncm (double in ) { incm = in; }
    void setSubtract ( double sub ) { subtract = sub; }
    void setTaxRate ( double rate ) { taxRate = rate; }
    void setAdd ( double Add ) { add = Add; }

    char getStatus () { return status; }
    double getIncm () { return incm; }
    double getsubtract () { return subtract; }
    double getTaxRate () { return taxRate; }
    double getAdd () { return add; }
    void calcIncome ();
};

//calcIncome
int main () {
    income _new;
    double ajIncome = 0, _incm = 0;
    char status = ' ';
    bool done = false;
    while ( !done ) {
        cout << "Please enter your TAXABLE INCOME:\n" << endl;
        cin >> _incm;
        if(cin.fail()) { cin.clear(); }
        if ( _incm <= 0) { cout << "the income must be greater than 0... \n" << endl; }
        if ( _incm > 0) { done = true; _new.setIncm(_incm); }
    }

    done = false;
    char stt [2] = " ";
    while ( !done ) {
        cout << "Please declare weather you are filing taxes jointly or single" << "\n";
        cout << "\t's' = single\n\t'm' = married" << endl;
        cin >> stt;
        if(cin.fail()) { cin.clear(); }
        if ( status == 's' || status == 'm' ) { done = true; _new.setStatus(stt[0]); }
        //if else { }
    }

    return 0;
};
```

This is part of a homework assignment so any pointers on bettering my programing would be **great**

Note:I am using Windows 7 with VS express C++ 2008

Comment: You should avoid using names that begin with underscore (`_`). Such names are reserved for use internally by the compiler. (This is used for example to add features such as `__declspec`)

Comment: @Wallter, It's a good idea to leave the code in your question as you originally posted it. If you copy the code from my answer into your question, the question doesn't make sense to future readers because you've corrected the code and removed the problem you were asking about.

Comment: not to poke fun, but you spelled whether wrong. :) At least I think you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`income` is the name of your class. `_incm` is the name of your variable. Perhaps you meant this (notice the use of `_incm` not `income`):

```
if (_incm <= 0) { cout << "the income must be greater than 0... \n" << endl; }
if (_incm > 0) { done = true; _new.setIncm(_incm); }
```

Frequently you use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for class names and lowercase for instance variable names. Since C++ is case-sensitive, they wouldn't conflict each other if they use different case.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is named `incom`, not `income`. `income` refers to a type, so the compiler gets confused and you get a syntax error when you try to compare that type against a value in line 50.

One note for bettering you programming would be to use more distinct variable names to avoid such confusions... ;)

Comment: You should change the name used in the comparison to be the name of the variable you want to compare.